# Accessing table returning by table-valued function from SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have table valued function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Functiont]()
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(   
SELECT d.*, b.Name AS Name, ps.Name AS PaymentSystemName, c.UserName AS UserName, c.FirstName AS ClientFirstName, c.LastName AS LastName, c.Number AS DocumentNumber, c.Id
FROM Document AS d
JOIN System AS ps ON d.SystemId = ps.Id
JOIN Client AS c ON c.Id = d.ClientId
LEFT JOIN Shop AS b ON b.Id = d.ShopId
WHERE d.OperationTypeId IN (2, 4, 5) AND c.Type = 1
)
```

And SP.  In that SP i have declared temporary table like this

```
DECLARE @tempTable AS TABLE 
(
   .. columns here ...
)
```

after declaring i just  inserting info

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fn_Functiont]()
Select @column1,colum2...,from @tempTable
```

The problem is that  i have to declare  a lot of  columns in @temptable and code  looks like ugly.So is there a better way to reading rows in SP from table valued function?

Comment: Your *inline table valued function* does not take any parameter (that's what it is meant to do). Doing so, it is quite the same as a `VIEW`. Btw: You should better not use the `*`, this can produce silly errors if your underlying objects change...

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why do you want to store the result in a table? You can just use the function exatly as any *real* table within your queries...

Comment: Could i  straightforward do select query for  to this function?I just want to retrieve info  from that  table which is returned by function and eventually return that info from SP

Comment: Yes, just use `SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_Functiont() AS SomeAlias;`. You can use this (as any table or view) in a query, even in joins etc. It is a good idea to use `AS SomeAlias` in order to give the function a temporary name, which can be used within the query (e.g. for joins)

Comment: Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of table Variable `@tempTable` Use Temp Table and Try This

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM [dbo].[fn_Functiont]()
```